# Facebook iframe page tab w/ iframe renders on Chrome, but not on Safari or Firefox

Tags: facebook, firefox, iframe, google-chrome, safari

The iframe loads properly on the page tab in chrome on my computer (I'm admin of the page), but when I try to view from another FB account on same computer via Safari or Firefox, no luck.

Also, the iframe doesn't load for others.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The iframe was not loading in Safari but it was loading in Firefox. And it was also loading correctly in Safari on another computer.

After about 3 hours of searching, trying and investigating, I finally found the solution.

It seemed to be a (simple) caching problem.
What I did is I cleared all website data of Safari.

Then it worked.